# What's another word for "house owner"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a *neutral* term that means "owner of the house"?

By *neutral* I mean words that do not suggest superiority, e.g. "landlord", "land owner", etc.

<sub>Note: "innkeeper" wouldn't work because it suggests owner of a hotel (a building primary for lease), instead of owner of a house (a building not primary for lease).</sub>

Comment: The term '**freeholder**' has a legal meaning in the UK and many English-speaking jurisdictions. It has been discussed on this site in postings *passim*.

Comment: The most common usage is "owner" -- with the context providing the required specific meaning of "house owner." There's no other single-word equivalent for a (one's) "house owner."

Comment: "Owner" is the antonym of "tenant." If the house is given out on lease (for rent), we could also say "lessor."

Comment: Surely any "superiority" is inherent in the fact of the ownership, and not imparted by the word *owner*, which is the simplest and most accurate term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**proprietor**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietor)

> [**proprietor**](http://www.knightstemplardagorhir.com/wiki/index.php?title=Have_an_understanding_of_How_Owner_Funding_Is_effective_So_that_you_can_Offer_The_house_Immediately): a person who has the legal right or exclusive title to something: owner

Also, consider [**homeowner**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/homeowner) and [**householder**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/householder).

> homeowner: a person that owns the house in which he or she lives
>
> householder: a person that occupies or owns a house

Answer (score 0):

I think **[property](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Property) owner** may be a neutral definition.

> A piece of real estate: has a swimming pool on the property.

Comment: However "owner" is not neutral.

Comment: I must have missed your concept of 'neutral'.

Comment: I mean "I'm your owner" isn't much neutral is it..

Comment: Don't think your landlord would address you saying 'I am your owner' anyway you have found your answer and that's fine :).

Comment: "householder" seems good, although of course there may be better alternatives.

Comment: I prefer Homeowner, for sone reason you don't want to use the word 'owner' .. don't think it has a negative connotation, in my view it is neutral, but you have to make your choice!

Comment: Hmm somehow the chat got deleted... what's happened?